Burning a lot of images to DVDs
Is there a way of taking a folder containing many, many images and making it into dvd size chunks for burning?
Using El Capitan on a Mac Pro (Early 2008).

Are any images in subfolders? Anything to sort by to usefully divide up the images - filename, date? Some divisions might fit on a single DVD, leaving fewer to work with. Next question: are you familiar with Automator and and/or Applescript, or willing to learn a bit? Your machine and OS version come with capable versions. You also have Perl available, one of the (still) great file manipulation languages. People here could guide. You might also find a compatible version of GraphicConverter, which can make catalogs and move/copy/convert images to new destinations including external drives. HTH

Also, how much data are we talking about in total (in GBs)?

Trying to remember how we used to do this 20 years ago when DVD archiving was a thing. ;-) If you're looking for the best way to store data without power, a mechanical hard drive is probably quickest, cheapest, easiest. Burned optical media are generally not that reliable long term. Some types/brands/specs last longer, but it's a bit of a lottery.

Thanks everybody, I will definitely look into Automator and AppleScript. I never knew GraphicConverter could so much. As to the total amount of GBs that's up in the air as I'm doing this for someone else who hasn't released that info yet.

The idea of the GB question is more that it must be a awful lot of images to validate the effort to create a semi-automated way. May be just easier to add folders til an DVD is full, and then proceed with the next.

I will try and convince them that getting a portable SSD would be a better option.

Whatever they choose, remind them that redundancy is key: every image on several DVD (ideally from different vendors), or on several SSD (again from different vendors).

Again, if this is for unpowered, long-term storage, you DON'T want to use an SSD; but rather a magnetic hard drive.

I will pass on this info, thanks.
